# Ensure item is in row N with Isotope layout

Tags: javascript, layout, jquery-isotope

So, we've got a collection of trinkets, of the form

```
<ul>
  <li class="trinket width-25"></li>
  <li class="trinket width-50"></li>
  <li class="trinket width-25"></li>
  <li class="trinket width-75"></li>
  <!-- many, many more trinkets-->
</ul>
```

Where width-75 is 75% wide, width-25 25% and so on. This is prettily arranged using [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co).

Now, I need to insert a full width, way taller, trinket, and I need to ensure 100% of the time it appears on a given row. 2nd, 7th, or whatever the end user actually decides.

How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

The packery layout will let you stamp items as explained in http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/packery.html